# SSL: does key file depends on host where it was created?

Tags: ssl

I have a .crt certificat and I want to generate the private key in .key format.
I want to know if the key file depends on the host where it was created?
For example, if I run

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
       -keyout mykey.key -out cert.crt
```

on two hosts where cert.crt is the same file, will the `mykey.key` file stays exactly the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command:

> openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
>          -keyout mykey.key -out cert.crt

Doesn't extract mykey.key from cert.crt, it generate both files (a new key and a new certificate request)

You can't extract the private key from the certificate or from the certificate request, it only contains the public key.